# php: setting a timezone by UTC offset

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

Using javascript I know that my users timezone is UTC +3.

Now I want to create DateTime object with this knowledge:

```
$usersNow = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("+3"));
```

I receive as a respsonse:

```
'Unknown or bad timezone (+2)'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

how about this...

```
$original = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("", 3*3600, false);
$modified = $original->setTimezone(new DateTimezone($timezoneName));
```

Comment: +1 just to make another +3^^ (just kidding, your answer is correct).

Comment: This is **wrong**, if PHP processes daylight savings.

Comment: Function timezone_name_from_abbr return false when called for +11 offset: `timezone_name_from_abbr("", 11*3600, false);`

Comment: This broke my production machine when passed Rio de Janeiro (-2*3600), I got `Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone`. I'll paste my fix in an answer below.

Answer (score 17):

You said:

> Using javascript I know that my users timezone is UTC +3.

You probably ran something like this:

```js
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

This returns the *current* offset from UTC in minutes, with positive values falling west of UTC.  It does *not* return a time zone!

A time zone is not an offset.  A time zone *has* an offset.  It can have *multiple different offsets*.  Often there are two offsets, one for standard time and one for daylight saving time.  A single numeric value cannot represent this alone.

- Example of a time zone:  `"America/New_York"`

  - Corresponding standard offset:  `UTC-5`
  - Corresponding daylight offset:  `UTC-4`

Besides the two offsets, also wrapped up in that time zone are the dates and times for transitioning between the two offsets so you know when they apply.  There's also a historical record of how the offsets and transitions may have changed over time.

See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

In your example case, you probably received a value of `-180` from javascript, representing a *current* offset of UTC+3.  But that's just the offset for that particular point in time! If you follow [minaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7276486/634824), you will get a time zone that makes the assumption that UTC+3 is *always* the correct offset.  That would work if the real time zone is something like [`"Africa/Nairobi"`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/kenya/nairobi) which has never used anything except UTC+3.  But for all you know your user could be in [`"Europe/Istanbul"`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/turkey/istanbul), which uses UTC+3 in the summer and UTC+2 in the winter.

Comment: This answer deserves way more upvotes. Very detailed explanation of the challenge @shealtiel is facing.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen I would agree, if a soltuion was proided.  All I see here, is a (possible) explanation of why the user was having difficulty.  Fine.  But what to do about it?

Comment: As explained in the answer, use an actual time zone identifier, such as `"America/New_York"`.  If you need to get that from JS, you can now do that. (in 2014 when this answer was written, you could not.). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602679/634824

Answer (score 9):

Modern answer:

```
$usersNow = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('+0300'));
```

Documentation:

> http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php

Answer (score 6):

Since PHP 5.5.10, DateTimeZone accepts an offset like "+3" :

https://3v4l.org/NUGSv

Answer (score 2):

This one takes Matthew's answer a step further to change the timezone of a date to any integer offset.

```
public static function applyHourOffset(DateTime $dateTime, int $hourOffset):DateTime
{
    $dateWithTimezone = clone $dateTime;

    $sign = $hourOffset < 0 ? '-' : '+';
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone($sign . abs($hourOffset));
    $dateWithTimezone->setTimezone($timezone);

    return $dateWithTimezone;
}
```

Note: I had a breakage in production due to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the docs on [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php), you need to pass a valid time zone and here are the [valid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) ones. Check the [others](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php), something there may help you.

Answer (score 1):

DateTimeZone requires a timezone not an offest

Comment: And how can I set a timezone knowing only the utc offset?

Comment: @shealtiel you can't

Comment: This is how you can make the timezone if you have offset only. Your welcome: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74054485/6907703

Answer (score 1):

did you try this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
 <?php
    echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
    echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
     echo strtotime("+5 hours");
    echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
    echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
    echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
    echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
    echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
    ?>
```

Comment: this can work. I don't really need the timezones name, just to compute the correct time. So "+3 hours" will do the trick fine

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this, I was facing the same problem, so in the end I extended the DateTime class and overrode the `__construct()` method to accept an offset (in minutes) instead of a timezone.

From there, my custom `__construct()` works out what the offset is in hours and minutes (e.g. -660 = +11:00) and then uses `parent::__construct()` to hand my date, custom formatted to include my offset, back to the original DateTime.

Because I'm always dealing with UTC times in my application, my class also modifies the UTC time by subtracting the offset, so passing Midnight UTC and an offset of -660 will show me 11am

My solution is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35916440/2301484

Answer (score 0):

I was directed to a solution thanks to Joey Rivera's link. Like what the others have said here, timezone is not an offset you do need a valid timezone.

This is what I am using for myself

```
$singapore_time = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore'));


var_dump( $singapore_time );
```

I myself have found it to be much more convenient to work with YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format. example.

```
$original = new DateTime("2017-05-29 13:14", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore'));
```