# PHP: DateTime::createFromFormat() with timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to convert date form from d/m/Y to Y-m-d with timezone offset.
I am able to convert from d/m/Y to Y-m-d with this code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

But I am not sure how to add the timezone offset.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use [`DateTime::setTimeZone()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Can I somehow use for example `+2:00` instead of `America/New_York`? I know you should use timezones and not offsets because of daylight savings etc. but on this environment timezones like `America/New_York` are not working.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7276486/250259) does what you need

Comment: Just to clarify. This does convert a date (user input and user's timezone) to the server timezone. So `America/New_York` is the timezone of the user?

Comment: Note that this example first creates `$date` in the server's timezone, and then when `setTimeZone()` is called, it *converts* it to "America/New_York".  In other words, it introduces a time component - `$date` is no longer at midnight.  Might not be a big deal for some, but it was for me!

Comment: Probably easiest way would be to create temp object and then new object base on temp. Like described below:
$dateInServerTimeZone = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateString);
 $dateInWantedTimeZone = new DateTime($dateInServerTimeZone->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), new DateTimeZone($createInZone));
Where $createInZone is a timzone name example "America/New_York" or "UTC" etc

Comment: This will convert the given datetime to the new timezone, but this is not the same as creating the given date within the timezone to begin with.  This answer will result in the digits changing, as it is representing the same datetime within a different timezone.  Alternatively, specifying the timezone as a parameter in \DateTime::createFromFormat will not change the digits, because the datetime will be created within that timezone to begin with.  Which answer is better depends on whether you want to convert to timezone or create in timezone.

Answer (score 33):

(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)
you actually enter the third parameter

> public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat(string $format ,
>   string $time[, DateTimeZone $timezone])

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer is not selected as solution. This is correct answer.

Comment: It does not work for me.. It seems like third parameter (`DateTimeZone` Object) was simply ignored.

The only way to achieve this was to use the validated answer published by @John Conde

I am running PHP 5.6.30

Comment: This works as described if you set $tz to the correct timezone, but you have to do it manually. new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()) sets the system default.

Comment: The 3rd parameter does absolutely bipkis.

Comment: @Kafoso Only if your default timezone happens to be GMT. If you're in any other timezone it's absolutely essential that you specify it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested both the solutions JohnConde and denoise.

with this script:

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$datetime_str = '2022-10-28 17:24:00';
$timezone_str = 'Europe/Rome';

$dt_test_denoise = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $datetime_str, 
                                         new DateTimeZone($timezone_str));
echo '$dt_test_denoise:';
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($dt_test_denoise);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

$dt_test_JohnConde = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $datetime_str);
$dt_test_JohnConde->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone_str));
echo '$dt_test_JohnConde:';
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($dt_test_JohnConde);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
```

execute this on http://phptester.net/ and you will see the differences.

I think the best is solution denoise!