# Programmatically determine using the UTC time at what offset a day/time is

Tags: php, datetime, utc, gmt

I have a cron job that fires hourly.  In my database I have rows that contain UTC offsets.  I'm trying to do the following programmatically.

```
function returnThisHourOffset($timeofday){
    //using the current UTC hour gmdate('G'), determine at what offset from the UTC the $timeofday currently exists (**and which day**).
}
```

I've written out what happens at each UTC for midnight and 5AM.

```
    UTC 23:00:00, At offset +1 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset +6 is 5AM, the next UTC day 
    UTC 22:00:00, At offset +2 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset +7 is 5AM, the next UTC day
    UTC 21:00:00, At offset +3 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset +8 is 5AM, the next UTC day
    UTC 20:00:00, At offset +4 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset +9 is 5AM, the next UTC day
    UTC 19:00:00, At offset +5 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset +10 is 5AM, the next UTC day
    UTC 18:00:00, At offset +6 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset +11 is 5AM, the next UTC day
    UTC 17:00:00, At offset +7 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset +12 is 5AM, the next UTC day
    UTC 16:00:00, At offset +8 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset -11 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 15:00:00, At offset +9 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset -10 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 14:00:00, At offset +10 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset -9 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 13:00:00, At offset +11 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset -8 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 12:00:00, At offset +12 is 12AM the next UTC day. At offset -7 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 11:00:00, At offset -11 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset -6 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 10:00:00, At offset -10 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset -5 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 09:00:00, At offset -9 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset -4 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 08:00:00, At offset -8 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset -3 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 07:00:00, At offset -7 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset -2 is 5AM, this UTC day 
    UTC 06:00:00, At offset -6 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset -1 is 5AM, this UTC day  
    UTC 05:00:00, At offset -5 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset 0 is 5AM, this UTC day
    UTC 04:00:00, At offset -4 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset +1 is 5AM, this UTC day
    UTC 03:00:00, At offset -3 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset +2 is 5AM, this UTC day
    UTC 02:00:00, At offset -2 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset +3 is 5AM, this UTC day
    UTC 01:00:00, At offset -1 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset +4 is 5AM, this UTC day
    UTC 00:00:00, At offset 0 is 12AM on the UTC day. At offset +5 is 5AM, this UTC day
```

So, for example `returnThisHourOffset(5)`  at UTC 8AM should return -3 with today's UTC date.  While `returnThisHourOffset(5)` at UTC 9PM (21:00:00) should return 8 with tomorrow's UTC date (since it's 9AM today and 8 hours later it's 5AM tomorrow).

Obviously, I'm not playing much with daylight savings or offsets > 12.  Just trying to keep it simple and it's still looking very complex.

This is my code which is strictly for getting the offset where midnight occurs or what could be `returnThisHourOffset(0)`  I'm looking for any time of day (0-23).

```
if(gmdate('A') == 'PM'){
        $offset = (24 - gmdate('G'));
        $today = gmdate("Y-m-d\T00\:00\:00", strtotime('tomorrow UTC'));
    } else {
        $offset = -1*(gmdate('G'));
        $today = gmdate("Y-m-d\T00\:00\:00", strtotime('today UTC'));
    }
```

I'm confident my code isn't the answer to this so I'm hoping someone else has tried to tackle this before in some fashion.  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276304/php-setting-a-timezone-by-utc-offset maybe?

Comment: I don't think I'll need to go through using timezone.

Answer (score 0):

This *looks like* it works but I'm open to better suggestions (since it's obviously very messy).

```
$utcHour = gmdate('G');
$timeofday = 5; // (0-23)

if($utcHour <= $timeofday){
    $offset = $timeofday - $utcHour;
    $today = gmdate("Y-m-d\T00\:00\:00", strtotime('today UTC'));
} elseif ($utcHour > $timeofday && $utcHour - $timeofday < 12){
    $offset = -1*($utcHour - $timeofday);
    $today = gmdate("Y-m-d\T00\:00\:00", strtotime('today UTC'));
} else {
    $offset = (24 - $utcHour) + $timeofday;
    $today = gmdate("Y-m-d\T00\:00\:00", strtotime('tomorrow UTC'));    
}
```