# Convert timezone using php?

Tags: php, date, timezone

How do I convert the timestamp `2015-06-05 14:05:01` to another timezone using php?

I've read and tried numerous ways listed on here but I cannot get the desired result. Using `date_format($date,"M d h:i A")` and `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')` I get `June 05 2:05 PM` which is the original origin of the server timezone and correct.

What I need is to convert `2015-06-05 14:05:01` using for example `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')` and `date_format($date,"M d h:i A")` to get the result `June 05 11:05 AM`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php):

```
// Create the DateTime() object and set the timezone to 'America/New_York'
$date = new DateTime('2015-06-05 14:05:01', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

// Change the timezone to 'America/Los_Angeles'
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

// Print out the date and time in the new timezone
echo $date->format('M d h:i A');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/376270)

Easy to read which makes it easy to mantain.

Comment: Thanks again, I know I tried something similar to this many times already but I didn't have it exactly right.

Comment: When I couldn't find a dupe quickly I figured it was worth writing an answer so we have one for the future.

Comment: I knew someone would tell me it was a dupe I've read them all, I thought it was worth posting again because I thought I might have the timestamp formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Is there a way to replace ('America/New_York') with ('-05:00')?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276304/php-setting-a-timezone-by-utc-offset) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Don't worry about it being a dup.  [It's ok](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I really appreciate it.