# PHP how to set up timezone for sitemap.xml lasmod tag for the date taken from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sitemap, utc, dst

I am writing php sitemap generator for my site where I publish articles. I would like to use timestamp from MySQL data base to put it into lastmod tag of sitemap.xml file. This is the code:

```
  <?php
//request to database:
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `date_update` FROM `table`';
$pdoobj_query = $db->query($sql);
$array_db = $pdoobj_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

//generating text of the sitemap.xml
$file = "sitemap.xml";
$sitemap_text = <<<MAP
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
MAP;

$number_of_array_elements = count($array_db);
$i=0;
while ($i < $number_of_array_elements){
    $sitemap_text .= "\t" . '<url>' . "\r\n";
    $sitemap_text .= "\t" . "\t" . '<loc>http://example.com/index.php?page=' . $array_db[$i]['id'] . '</loc>' . "\r\n";

    $sitemap_text .= "\t" . "\t" . '<lastmod>' . date('c', strtotime($array_db[$i]['date_update'])) . '</lastmod>' . "\r\n";
    $sitemap_text .= "\t" . "\t" . '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>' . "\r\n";
    $sitemap_text .= "\t" . "\t" . '<priority>0.9</priority>' . "\r\n";

    $sitemap_text .= "\t" . '</url>' . "\r\n";
    $i++;
}

$sitemap_text .='</urlset>';

file_put_contents($file, $sitemap_text);
?>
```

I get the following out put for lastmod tag:

```
...

    <lastmod>2016-02-06T01:53:44+04:00</lastmod>

...
```

UTC +04:00 provided by PHP for 'Europe/Moscow' is not currently correct since Russian legislation has changed. It must be UTC +03:00. Look here for historic DST changes: [Time Zone in Moscow, Russia](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/russia/moscow)

[I tried to use the following advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276304/php-setting-a-timezone-by-utc-offset):

```
$original = new DateTime("now");
$timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("", 3*3600, false);
$modified = $original->setTimezone(new DateTimezone($timezoneName));
echo $modified->format('c');
```

But php picks up 'Europe/Moscow' time zone and returns 2016-02-09T04:41:53+04:00  that is one hour ahead of current time.

Is there any way to force php to format timestamp extracted from MySQL table with UTC +03:00 time zome?