# How to make a date given a utc offset in minutes using php?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, datetime

I use this method using js on the frontend to get the utc offset in minutes. It gives me a result like -300 for UTC+500

```js
const d = new Date();
let diff = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Now how do I make the date in php using this offset? More specifically, how do I convert this offset to something acceptable by a solution like this:

```
$usersNow = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('+0300'));
```

Do I have to manually get my offset to a string like this?

Comment: Do you mean "-300" for "UTC-0500", rather than "UTC+500"?

Comment: @IMSoP
Im at +5 so I guess -300 represents UTC+500

Comment: Well, an hour contains 60 minutes, so 300 / 60 = 5. Format that, and you're virtually there. It gets a bit more trickier if you want to handle half-hour time zones.

Comment: @MuhammadMubashirullahDurrani 300 minutes is 5 hours, but why would the sign (+/-) be wrong? I suspect you've got a subtraction the wrong way around somewhere.

Comment: @IMSoP I'll verify again but this is the value that gets logged and I send it without any manipulation

Comment: `The number of minutes returned by getTimezoneOffset() is positive if the local time zone is behind UTC, and negative if the local time zone is ahead of UTC. For example, for UTC+10, -600 will be returned.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: @Paolo Oh, wow, thanks for the link. Makes about as much sense as [zero-indexed months](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTimeZone` class is a wrapper around functions in a library by Derick Rethans called "timelib", so we can check the source code to confirm our options.

The constructor first calls [timelib_parse_zone](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/9d2ed6578188ce3cd4a6128fa79008a8ae33866d/parse_date.re#L898) which recognises "GMT+", "GMT-", "+", and "-" as prefixes for offsets, and passes the remaining string to [timelib_parse_tz_cor](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/9d2ed6578188ce3cd4a6128fa79008a8ae33866d/parse_date.re#L806).

As pointed out in a comment by [Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1579327/paolo), [the JS Date.getTimezoneOffset function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) returns its offset with the opposite sign from most other notations: -300 represents an offset of 300 minutes *ahead of* UTC. We can therefore begin our string with "+" for a negative input, and "-" for a positive input, then format the rest of the value ignoring sign.

That function handles the following formats, based on the length of the string:

- length 1: /* H */
- length 2: /* HH */
- length 3: /* H:M */
- length 4: /* H:MM, HH:M, HHMM */
- length 5: /* HH:MM */
- length 6: /* HHMMSS */
- length 8: /* HH:MM:SS */

If you only care about whole-hour offsets, the simplest format would be to include only the hours (the "H" and "HH" cases). However, there are no formats that *only* have minutes.

To cover all timezones, you'll need one of the formats that includes both hours and minutes.

Looking at the code, a value of "+123" will be interpreted the same as "+01:23", but it could theoretically mean "+12:03" instead, so it's best to avoid that ambiguity. We can either insert zeroes to make a fixed length format like "HHMM", or we can include the ':' separator, which allows one or two digits on either side.

A verbose implementation could therefore look like this:

```
// Sign is mandatory in the string; it's the opposite of what JS gave us
$sign = ($jsOffset < 0) ? '+' : '-';

// Discard sign from offset for remaining calculations
$absOffsetMins = abs($jsOffset);

// Hours is offset divided by 60, discarding fractions
$offsetHourPart = intdiv($absOffsetMins, 60);

// Minutes is the remainder of that division: offset modulo 60
$offsetMinPart = $absOffsetMins % 60;

// Put it together; depending on value, result will be in format
// +H:M, +H:MM, +HH:M, or +HH:MM, all of which are supported
$timezoneString = $sign . $offsetHourPart . ':' . $offsetMinPart;

// Make the object
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezoneString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are other ways to achieve the same goal, for the sake of saving time for others, here is another solution for javascript and php.

Frontend, get the time zone instead of offset

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
// Output: Asia/Karachi
```

On the backend:

```
        $systemDate = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
        $systemDate = $systemDate->format('d/m/Y');
```